# jQuery checkbox disable/enable secondary inputs based on checkbox value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a form (it's a WordPress plugin, Contact 7, fyi) that uses an exclusive checkbox. There are two checkbox choices, yes and no. If they check yes, I have a text field that I am enabling (I have disabled it by default). If they check no, I have a second exclusive checkbox  with 2 boxes that I am enabling (also by default). As you can surmise, when the user selects yes, it also should disable the second checkbox. And if they choose no, I want the text field to return to disabled state.

So I have this working, except, it doesn't recognize the change event; in other words, if I check yes, it enables the text field, but if I then check no, it does not update the associated states of the other input elements. I have to uncheck the no, then recheck it, in order for it to perform the function. Here is my jQuery code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p#myTextFieldHolder input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#mySecondCheckBoxHolder input:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);

    $("#myCheckBoxHolder input").change(function() {

        if ($(":checked").val() == "If yes, what is the estimated closing date?") {

            $('p#myTextFieldHolder input:text').val('').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#mySecondCheckBoxHolder input:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
        } else if ($(":checked").val() == "No:") {
            $('p#myTextFieldHolder input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#mySecondCheckBoxHolder input:checkbox').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('p#myTextFieldHolder input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#mySecondCheckBoxHolder input:checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    })
});​
```

Any suggestions on how to account for this and correct it? Thank you.

Comment: It will be good if you can post your MarkUp ..

Comment: So only one checkbox can be checked at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/mWt6Q/) of what you asked for, hope it helps

```
$(function(){
    $('#chkboxes input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            if($(this).attr('id')=='yes')
            {         
                $('#txt1').prop('disabled', false);
                $('#chkno input:checkbox').prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false);
                $('#no').prop('checked', false);  
            }
            else
            {
                $('#txt1').val('').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#chkno input:checkbox').prop('disabled', false);   
                $('#yes').prop('checked', false);             
            }
        }
    });
});​
```